# How to create Views with less queries in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

Models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, blank=True, default='', unique=True)

class BookTranslation(models.Model):
  book = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name='book_translations')
  language = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES)

class Chapter(models.Model):
  chapter = models.IntegerField()
  book_translation = models.ForeignKey(BookTranslation, related_name='related_chapters')

class Page(models.Model):
  chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, related_name='related_pages')
  page = models.IntegerField()
  url = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<language>[\w-]{2})-book/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<chapter>\d+)/(?P<page>\d+)/$",
  PageView(), 
  name="page")
```

I tried different approaches to make PageView() and ended up with this:

```
class PageView(DetailView):
  model = Book
  template_name = 'bookinfo/book_page.html'
  context_object_name = 'book'

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(PageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    context['book_translation'] = BookTranslation.objects.get(
        book=context['book'], language=self.kwargs['language'])

    context['chapter'] = Chapter.objects.get(
        book_translation=context['book_translation'].id, chapter=self.kwargs['chapter'])

    context['page'] = Page.objects.get(
        chapter=context['chapter'].id, page=self.kwargs['page'])

    context['chapter_list'] = Chapter.objects.filter(
        book_translation=context['book_translation'].id)

    context['page_list'] = Page.objects.filter(
        chapter=context['chapter'].id)
    return context
```

But this way, every time i open this page, i make 6 requests to the DB, when i could easily get the arguments in context['book'], context['book_translation'] context['chapter'] and context['page'] with a singole SQL query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Book b, BookTranslation bt, Chapter c, Page p
WHERE b.slug=self.kwargs['slug'] and 
  b.name=bt.book_id and
  bt.language=self.kwargs['language'] and 
  c.book_translation_id=bt.id and
  c.chapter=self.kwargs['chapter'] and 
  c.id=p.chapter_id and 
  p.page=self.kwargs['page']
```

Can someone explain me how can i make this View(preferably class based) more performance? I probably didn't understand how they work...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve related foreign keys use `select_related` by overriding `get_queryset` of `SingleObjectMixin` as follows:

```
class PageView(DetailView):

    ...

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super(PageView, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        return qs.select_related()
```

This will fetch all related objects in a single query, so as long as the queryset is not evaluated, all the related objects in your view's `get_context_data` should not be queried again.

Refer: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#select-related